# Python errors while deploying Azure Data Factory via github action (azure/data-factory-deploy-action)

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-data-factory

For context: I have 3 data factory instances (dev, qa and prod) and each of them access their own linked services, i.e., each 'stage' has its own storage account and corresponding connections. Publishing is disabled from the data factory, so it only happens via deployments on push to main branch.

I'm trying to deploy Azure Data Factory using the Azure/data-factory-deploy-action on a self-hosted runner. I've followed the steps similar to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-with-github-actions/ba-p/3768493).
I install python, powershell and azure for powershell in the workflow, build the ARM templates and deploy. But when I try to deploy, I encounter this error with python asyncio: `AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_ssock'`.

The problem is it succeeds half the time without any changes in the codes. Why do only some of the deployments work and some don't?

I thought it was because of the publish config. Does having the same `publish_config.json`, and hence the same publish branch name for 3 ADFs make a difference?

Could it be because some dependency is missing in the runner? The runners are clean and I install the dependencies in the previous steps.

I've included a full log below:

```
> Run Azure/data-factory-deploy-action@v1.2.0
> Run if('false' -ne 'true') { Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force }
> Run /runner/_work/_actions/Azure/data-factory-deploy-action/v1.2.0/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1 `
Getting triggers
Stopping deployed triggers

Stopping trigger WeekdayTrigger
True
Stopping trigger WeeklyTrigger
True
> Run azure/arm-deploy@v1
  with:
    resourceGroupName: ***
    template: ARMTemplateForFactory.json
    parameters: ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json factoryName=*** 
    failOnStdErr: true
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64/lib
    AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT: 
    AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT: 
Validating template...
Creating deployment...
Error: Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x7f[49](https://<github-enterprise>/datafactory-artifacts/actions/runs/140266/jobs/283784#step:9:52)dfbd0f70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 690, in __del__

Error:     self.close()
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/asyncio/unix_events.py", line [68](https://<github-enterprise>/datafactory-artifacts/actions/runs/140266/jobs/283784#step:9:72), in close
    super().close()
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 87, in close
    self._close_self_pipe()
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 94, in _close_self_pipe
    self._remove_reader(self._ssock.fileno())
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_ssock'

Error: Deployment process failed as some lines were written to stderr
```

Comment: You might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/Azure/arm-deploy/issues/new/choose) on its repo as well including all the details.

Comment: Thank you. I had created an issue in azure/data-factory-deploy-action but not in azure/arm-deploy. I'll do that now.